# JS how to Sum/Average?

Tags: javascript

I have an object and need to sum/average of each dynamic span. Can't seem to convert those to numbers though. Please Help.

[Console Log](https://s23.postimg.org/pofiv98qj/1.png)
[Code Sample](https://s23.postimg.org/6km7ewvwb/2.png)

```
Expand/Collapse Created : 1/3/2017 ‎<span>(10)‎</span>
Expand/Collapse Created : 1/4/2017 ‎<span>(38)‎</span>
Expand/Collapse Created : 1/5/2017 ‎‎<span>(13)</span>
Expand/Collapse Created : 1/6/2017 ‎‎<span>(35)</span>
Expand/Collapse Created : 1/9/2017 ‎‎<span>(46)</span>
Expand/Collapse Created : 1/10/2017 ‎‎<span>(17)</span>
Expand/Collapse Created : 1/11/2017 ‎‎<span>(27)</span>


var arr = [];
    $(".ms-gb span").each(function(index, elem){
        arr.push($(this).text());
    });

    $("#result").text(arr.join("+"));  // (10)+‎(38)+‎(13)+‎(35)+‎(46)+‎(17)+‎(27)

var allNumbers =   document.getElementById('result').innerText; // (10)+‎(38)+‎(13)+‎(35)+‎(46)+‎(17)+‎(27)
    allNumbers = allNumbers.replace(/["'()]/g,""); // ‎‎10+‎38+‎13+‎35+‎46+‎17+‎28
var newString  = allNumbers.split("+");  // Object - ["‎10", "‎38", "‎13", "‎35", "‎46", "‎17", "‎27"]
```

Comment: try looking into the parseInt function, e.g. `parseInt("10")` returns the number 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can strip out non-numeric characters, parse each number, and then perform the addition within the loop.

```js
// variables
var sum = 0;
var average = 0;
var numOfSpan = $('span').length;

// each span loop
$('span').each(function(key, val){
  // add the value of the span to the sum var
  sum+= parseInt($(this).text().replace(/\D/g,''));  
  
  // on the last itteration ...
  if(key == (numOfSpan - 1)) {
    
    // calulate average
    average = sum / numOfSpan;
    
    // log sum and average
    console.log('sum = ' + sum);
    console.log('average = ' + average);
  }
});
```

```html
<span>(10)</span>
‎<span>(38)</span>
<span>(13)</span>
<span>(35)</span>
‎<span>(46)</span>
‎‎<span>(17)</span>
<span>(27)</span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for!! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

well you're pretty close. i'd recommend using the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function

```
var sum = allNumbers.reduce(function(a,b){ return +a + +b; }, 0)
```

the [plus signs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) in front of a and b might look weird, but its a quick way to coerce a string into a number in javascript

Comment: Wow, unary +, this kind of questions always attract `parseInt(parseInt(parseInt(a) + parseInt(b)))` answers.

Comment: ahh unary, thats the name of it. i'll edit a doc link in there, thanks!

Comment: While this is right, my first instinct when seeing this is "eww". I prefer a more explicit `parseInt` for clarity. We're not golfing here.

Comment: @Carcigenicate If you want to be explicit, use `Number`. My rule of thumb is to never use `parseInt` unless I really want its exact behavior: extract the integer at the beginning of a string.

Comment: Only thing is if there is non numeric characters present +a will return NaN

Comment: @Oriol Ya, I should have mentioned that. I typically use it to parse CSS  values since they have a unit after them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate your array and then change every string to number. After that you can add every elements to itself.

```
var a = 0;
for(var i=0;i<newString.length;i++) {
    a += parseInt(newString[i]);}
```

And then a will be the sum

Comment: Getting NaN as the result.

Comment: @user1545463 That likely means one of the strings you're trying to parse isn't parsable as a number. Make sure none of your strings are prefixed with any non-digit characters. It's probably a `(` looking at your example. You'll need to remove the parentheses.

Comment: Right, that was the issue. This is that the spans are populated dynamically and I am not able to remove the parentheses. Josh Sangers code did the trick.